# Can I make large changes to a git repo without rendering git-blame useless?

Tags: git, git-blame

So, let's say I have a repo and it's development has been... organic.

In an effort to wrangle things, I've instituted coding standards with attendant linting files.

I'm using a nice linter that is able to fix a lot of the mundane issues automatically.

If I run that against a repo and commit the changes, the git-blame information for any significantly modified files will be rendered useless.

So, is there a way to avoid this problem?

For instance, is there a way to assign blame for a line to someone other than the committer? A way to commit without changing blame information?

Another approach might be possible (if commits are not signed): to have a script fix on a line by line basis and commit each change as the appropriate user... but that would create a huge chain of commits in your repo...

Using `git blame` to view prior commits, once the clean up has taken place, doesn't really address this question.

Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Not quite - that question solves the problem of seeing who is responsible for a line prior to the cleanup.
This question is trying to avoid the need for that altogether.

Comment: Another possible dup target is https://stackoverflow.com/q/4112410/2747593