# Git commit without a new author (keep old lines' authors)

Tags: git, blame, git-blame

I'm adding eslint/prettier to my repository for code formatting, styling, etc. The issue is that when people run `git blame` I will now be know as the author of tons of lines of code in our project.

I found this [blog post](https://www.moxio.com/blog/43/ignoring-bulk-change-commits-with-git-blame) which shows that I can use `git blame --ignore-rev` to ignore a certain commit on `git blame` but that requires people to know that I've made this commit and then it also requires them to lookup or use that hash every time.

Is there a way, either when I make the commit or after I've made the commit, to keep the author of those lines of code as they are before the linting? I don't want to have no author, I just wanted them to remain unchanged.

Comment: You can't do that, but you can e.g. ignore whitespace when blame-ing: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4112410/3001761

Comment: I guess the lesson to be learned from this is to get code formatting setup when you create a git repo